# ListLinePlot function in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I wish to plot a vector with the help of `ListLinePlot` function in mathematica. I want to change the scale of the Y axis in it. I cannot find a way in the documentation. The vector that I wish to plot is given below

```
{{1, 0}, {1., 0.00404858}, {1.00001, 0.00809717}, {1.00002, 
 0.0121457}, {1.00003, 0.0161943}, {1.00005, 0.0202429}, {1.00007, 
 0.0242915}, {1.00009, 0.0283401}, {1.00012, 0.0323887}, {1.00015, 
 0.0364372}, {1.00018, 0.0404858}, {1.00022, 0.0445344}, {1.00027, 
 0.048583}, {1.00031, 0.0526316}, {1.00036, 0.0566802}, {1.00042, 
 0.0607287}, {1.00047, 0.0647773}, {1.00053, 0.0688259}, {1.0006, 
 0.0728745}, {1.00067, 0.0769231}, {1.00074, 0.0809717}, {1.00081, 
 0.0850202}, {1.00089, 0.0890688}, {1.00098, 0.0931174}, {1.00106, 
 0.097166}, {1.00115, 0.101215}, {1.00125, 0.105263}, {1.00134, 
 0.109312}, {1.00145, 0.11336}, {1.00155, 0.117409}, {1.00166, 
 0.121457}, {1.00177, 0.125506}, {1.00189, 0.129555}, {1.00201, 
 0.133603}, {1.00213, 0.137652}, {1.00226, 0.1417}, {1.00239, 
 0.145749}, {1.00252, 0.149798}, {1.00266, 0.153846}, {1.0028, 
 0.157895}, {1.00295, 0.161943}, {1.0031, 0.165992}, {1.00325, 
 0.17004}, {1.00341, 0.174089}, {1.00357, 0.178138}, {1.00373, 
 0.182186}, {1.0039, 0.186235}, {1.00407, 0.190283}, {1.00424, 
 0.194332}, {1.00442, 0.198381}, {1.0046, 0.202429}, {1.00479, 
 0.206478}, {1.00498, 0.210526}, {1.00517, 0.214575}, {1.00537, 
 0.218623}, {1.00557, 0.222672}, {1.00577, 0.226721}, {1.00598, 
 0.230769}, {1.00619, 0.234818}, {1.0064, 0.238866}, {1.00662, 
 0.242915}, {1.00684, 0.246964}, {1.00707, 0.251012}, {1.0073, 
 0.255061}, {1.00753, 0.259109}, {1.00776, 0.263158}, {1.008, 
 0.267206}, {1.00825, 0.271255}, {1.00849, 0.275304}, {1.00874, 
 0.279352}, {1.009, 0.283401}, {1.00926, 0.287449}, {1.00952, 
 0.291498}, {1.00978, 0.295547}, {1.01005, 0.299595}}
```

It is actually a list of lists. when I plot it, the scale on the Y-axis takes an increment of 0.05. I wish to make it 0.2. Also I want some more of the X axis to be shown, i.e from 0.99 to 1.01. Currently it shows only from 1.00 to 1.01.!!

Comment: I'm glad you've been able to find help for your Mathematica problems here on [so]. It would also be nice if you took the time to upvote those who have helped you by providing answers for your questions.

Comment: @yoda: sure, how do i do it...??

Comment: You can click the up arrow (above the answer score) next to the answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{.99, 1.01}, All}, Ticks -> {Automatic, {0., .2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This looks fine but I wish to have a continuous curve rather than a dotted one....suggest something..!!